# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sgp.postcodebase.com

Tags: curl, networking, dns, host

I'm not able to ping/curl this sgp.postcodebase.com though it's running on different system and on the browser. I'm getting the following error:

```
curl http://sgp.postcodebase.com/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sgp.postcodebase.com
```

Can anybody explain what's wrong and from where do I start debugging this error ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your curl command, but that url is not known.  To debug, I would start by doing a nslookup on the parent domain

```
nslookup postcodebase.com
```

The error message should give you a clue.  In the example you give the error message is "** server can't find postcodebase.com: NXDOMAIN" which says to me that you have a DNS issue.  Go speak to your networking guys about getting the url registered in the DNS if this is not a public domain.  If it is public, then speak to the website owners.